# Tron: Legacy Soundtrack similar

Tags: soundtrack, electronic-music, similar-artists

I am in love with the *Tron: Legacy* Soundtrack by Daft Punk. I like their regular stuff but this soundtrack with orchestra as well as electronic elements is just fantastic! I also love the *Portal 2* Soundtrack. I was wondering what other soundtracks / artists have a similar sound to these ones. And is there a special name for this kind of genre or is it just considered electronic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arranger and orchestrator working with Daft Punk on *Tron: Legacy* is Joseph Trapanese. He has worked on a long list of movie and television soundtracks, and combining electronics with orchestra seems to be his specialty. Check out some of his other projects.

[Joseph Trapanese at IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2468967/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr1283)

[Joseph Trapanese's website](http://www.joecomposer.com)

Comment: _Tron: Uprising_ is a cool one too. Thanks for the info!